# Typescript nested type variables

Tags: typescript, types

Have this:

```js
type Format<A, R> = (arg: A) => R;

type FormatString<R> = (str: string) => R;

type FormatNumber<R> = (num: number) => R;
```

Would like to have this:

```js
type Format<A<R>> = (arg: A) => R;

type FormatString = Format<string>;

type FormatNumber = Format<number>;
```

Or this:

```js
type Format<A, R> = (arg: A) => R;

type FormatString = Format<string>;

type FormatNumber = Format<number>;
```

Currying or partial application for types is what I'm looking for. Or maybe some other workaround which keeps the code dry.

Comment: Without [higher-kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) this is not really possible without duplication.

Comment: Do you have a use case for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add R as another type parameter on the partially specialized types.

```
type Format<A, R> = (arg: A) => R;

type FormatString<R> = Format<string, R>;

type FormatNumber<R> = Format<number, R>;
```